# Solid two-color stroke

Tags: svg

How would I create a path/rect with a two-color stroke? E.g. if the stroke-width is 2px, I want the outer 1px to be black and the inner 1px to be blue. Should I use gradients or patterns, or will I need to resort to some sort of hack?

Comment: an easy way would be to just make two shapes and have one be underneath the other and slightly bigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no support for defining the position of the stroke with regards to the path/rect (inside, middle, outaide)

As in this this proposal: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Stroke_position

I think you have to make two rects/paths and stroke them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You could make Z's 2 piece solution a set so that it behaves and can be treated like a single Element